# Input Validation vs Model Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I came a cross an issue today in which one of the properties I use for model binding is an integer with `[Required]` attribute. However, model binder was happily skipping it because I mistakenly did not provide a form for it in the view. When I fixed it, it worked nicely.

I then read this [article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html), but could not really understand when or where input validation is triggered instead of model validation, or vice versa.

Can I use both at the same time, and how can I switch between them?

P.S.: I am developing on MVC 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the issue lies in the fact that `[Required]` attribute on non-nullable properties has no effect. At the end, even if a value was not supplied, class initialization will assign the default value for non-nullable properties, which will them be seen by model binder as valid. For example, if no value was supplied to `public int x { get; set; }`, then class initialization will assign it to 0 (default for integral values).

The solution for this case is to make those non-nullable properties nullable, by suffixing `?` after the type `public int? x { get; set; }`.

Input validation was used in MVC 1 and earlier previews off MVC2 to validate only those submitted values, and not caring about what is actually defined inside the model. However, this has changed to model validation in which validation system inspects the model bound for validation errors. However, the required attribute is such a subtle attribute that might confuse some.